# Relative references for CSS and JS files in an iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, wkwebview, ios12

I want to allow users to create `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JS` files and preview them. I give them the option to preview the `HTML` file in a `WKWebView`. I do this by passing the whole `HTML` file as a string to the `WKWebView`'s `loadHTMLString` function in my Swift code.

If someone writes `<script src="index.js"></script>` within their `HTML` file being previewed, I want that to work. Where will `WKWebView` look for the `index.js` file? Should I be writing all 3 files to a temporary directory in **iOS** and letting `WKWebView` simply load the `HTML` file from there?